# Select Tag Options won't work with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to use ng-repeat with the options within a Select menu like so

```
<select name="category" id="category" ng-model="rumor.category" validation-pattern="requiredOnly" error-icon>
<option ng-repeat="cat in formOptions.categories" value="{{ cat }}" >{{ cat }}</option>
</select>
```

However on rendering my select is empty and when inspecting the console I see the following:

```
<select id="category" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ng-model="rumor.category" name="category" required="required">
<option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
</select>
```

Now I know I should really use `ng-options` on the select menu however I wish to include  **angular-ui / ui-select2** which is incompatable with `ng-options` and the documentation recomends using a repeater (see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2)

When I use the same repeater on a different tag, for example:

```
 <p ng-repeat="cat in formOptions.categories" value="{{ cat }}" >{{ cat }}</p>
```

the repeater works as expected. Any ideas why this is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post `formOptions.categories"`?

Comment: try using an array of objects, not array of strings. Very possibly a scope inheritance issue

Comment: formOptions.categories is an array of strings... when changing this to an array of objects I still get the same error, this is it now:

$scope.formOptions.categories = [
            {'cat' : '1'},
            {'cat' : '2'},
            {'cat' : '3'},
            {'cat' : '4'}
        ];

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `ng-repeat` for select options. Use `ng-options` ([link](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect)) instead:

```
<select name="category" 
        id="category"
        ng-model="rumor.category"
        validation-pattern="requiredOnly"
        error-icon
        ng-options="c.cat for c in formOptions.categories">
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, but like I mentioned previously "I know I should really use ng-options on the select menu however I wish to include angular-ui / ui-select2 which is incompatible with ng-options and the documentation recommends using a repeater (see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2)". I'll keep trying and hopfully something will work

Comment: Heh, whoops. I notice you're not actually invoking the `ui-select2` directive. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I noticed that before, I have put it in and the styling works, the real problem here is the ng-repeat not working, not the ui-select2 per-se

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use select option with ng-repeat.

JS:

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.categories = [ {'cat' : '1'}, {'cat' : '2'}, {'cat' : '3'}, {'cat' : '4'}] ;

}

HTML:

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <select ng-model="item.value">
            <option ng-repeat="cat in categories" value="{{cat.cat}}">{{cat.cat}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

You can also fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/usmanfaisal/vHw7N/
```